# data not updating on google sheet using python

Tags: python, post

I am following the python 100 day course in Udemy, I am trying to update the "iataCode" column using post from the request library. I am not getting any error but the data is not updated

I was expecting for the data in the empty column "iataCode" to be updated with "TESTING"

```
import requests
import json
END_POINT_SHEET="https://api.sheety.co/6adb0e05a44ead17ca9ff3a936123348/copyOfFlightDeals/prices"


response=requests.get(END_POINT_SHEET)

r=response.json()
print(r)
response_lis=r["prices"]
print(response_lis)
#for _ in response_lis:
    #if ["iataCode"]=" ":
       # print("its an empty column")
#print(r["prices"][0]["iataCode"])

# to add to post the sheety

for _ in response_lis:

    sheet_input = {
            "prices": {
                "iataCode": "TESTING",

            }
        }


    response_post=requests.post(END_POINT_SHEET,json=sheet_input)
    print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing wrong response in last line of your code
instead of `print(response.text)` it should be `print(response_post.text)`

Then you will get your error, which is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Bad Request. The JSON payload should be inside a root property called 'price'. Check https://sheety.co/docs for more details."
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of "prices" it should be "price".

```py
sheet_input = {
            "price": {
                "iataCode": "TESTING",

            }
        }
```

Also, if you are updating the value of row, then you need to use PUT method, not POST. And in endpoint of the sheet, you also need to provide the 'id' of the row.

```py
import requests
import json
END_POINT_SHEET="https://api.sheety.co/6adb0e05a44ead17ca9ff3a936123348/copyOfFlightDeals/prices"


response=requests.get(END_POINT_SHEET)

r=response.json()
print(r)
response_lis=r["prices"]
print(response_lis)
#for _ in response_lis:
    #if ["iataCode"]=" ":
       # print("its an empty column")
#print(r["prices"][0]["iataCode"])

# to add to post the sheety

for i in response_lis:

    sheet_input = {
            "price": {
                "iataCode": "TESTING",

            }
        }

    END = f"{END_POINT_SHEET}/{i.get('id')}"
    print(END_POINT_SHEET)
    response_post=requests.put(END,json=sheet_input)
    print(response_post.text)
```

`END = f"{END_POINT_SHEET}/{i.get('id')}"`
The 'END' variable will store the endpoint with id of row and pass as an endpoint for all the rows from 'response_lis''

So this is your final code.